# Converting string to float

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program that tallies the values in a file. For example, I am given a file with numbers like this

2222 (First line)

4444 (Second line)

1111 (Third line)

My program takes in the name of an input file (E.G. File.txt), and the column of numbers to tally. So for example, if my file.txt contains the number above and i need the sum of column 2, my function should be able to print out 7(2+4+1)

```
t1 = open(argv[1], "r")
number = argv[2]
k = 0

while True:
   n = int(number)
   t = t1.readline()
   z = list(t)

   if t == "":
       break

   k += float(z[n])

t1.close()
print k
```

This code works for the first column when I set it to 0, but it doesn't return a consistent result when I set it to 1 even though they should be the same answer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: if inputing 0 works i cant see why 1 wouldnt, what debugging have you tried?

Comment: It works for me. Dont see any problems.

Comment: What do you get with 1?

Comment: Note that you should never need float precision. `k += float(z[n])` is exactly equal to `k += int(z[n])` since you're only ever getting one character (e.g. an integer) worth of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat uglier implementation that demonstrates the cool-factor of `zip`:

```
def sum_col(filename, colnum):
    with open(filename) as inf:
        columns = zip(*[line.strip() for line in inf])
        return sum([int(num) for num in list(columns)[colnum]])
```

`zip(*iterable)` flips from row-wise to columnwise, so:

```
iterable = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd']
zip(*iterable) == ['abcd','abcd','abcd'] # kind of...
```

zip objects aren't subscriptable, so we need to cast as list before we subscript it (doing `[colnum]`). Alternatively we could do:

```
    ...
    for _ in range(colnum-1):
        next(columns) # skip the columns we don't need
    return sum([int(num) for num in next(columns)])
```

Or just calculate all the sums and grab the sum that we need

```
    ...
    col_sums = [sum(int(num) for num in column) for column in columns]
    return col_sums[colnum]
```